# Openshift: war file disappears

Tags: jboss, openshift, war, wildfly

I deployed war-file to openshift via rhc and wildfly administrative console. It works fine. But after few days (approximately one week) war disappears. The administrative tool on openshift and wildfly console works correctly. Then I redeploy war and it's ok again. Is there any time limit on openshift? Any ideas what is the problem?

UPD: log

```
==> wildfly/logs/server.log.2015-02-23 <==
2015-02-23 11:25:04,282 INFO  [org.hornetq.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 61) HQ221003: trying to deploy queue jms.queue.ExpiryQueue
2015-02-23 11:25:04,282 INFO  [org.jboss.as.messaging] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 61) JBAS011601: Bound messaging object to jndi name java:/jms/queue/ExpiryQueue
2015-02-23 11:25:04,805 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS010406: Registered connection factory java:/JmsXA
2015-02-23 11:25:05,107 INFO  [org.hornetq.ra] (MSC service thread 1-6) HornetQ resource adaptor started
2015-02-23 11:25:05,109 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.services.resourceadapters.ResourceAdapterActivatorService$ResourceAdapterActivator] (MSC service thread 1-6) IJ020002: Deployed: file://RaActivatorhornetq-ra
2015-02-23 11:25:05,113 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS010401: Bound JCA ConnectionFactory [java:/JmsXA]
2015-02-23 11:25:05,113 INFO  [org.jboss.as.messaging] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS011601: Bound messaging object to jndi name java:jboss/DefaultJMSConnectionFactory
2015-02-23 11:25:06,079 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015961: Http management interface listening on http://127.6.80.1:9990/management
2015-02-23 11:25:06,102 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015951: Admin console listening on http://127.6.80.1:9990
2015-02-23 11:25:06,102 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015874: WildFly 8.2.0.Final "Tweek" started in 24894ms - Started 226 of 352 services (168 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
```

================================

Looks like it restarts every week.

Comment: Did you do any git push or restart your application during that time?  Is there anything in the log files?

Comment: I didn't change my repo. Where could I find the logs?

Comment: You can use the rhc tail command, or ssh to your application and look int ~/app-root/logs

Comment: How exactly did you put your war file on the server? Did you remove the src folder and pom.xml?

Comment: I use rhc `port-forward` then I go to 127.6.80.1:9990 to administrative tool and deploy my war on deployments tab. My war doesn't contain pom.xml or src folder but it includes WEB-INF folder with .class files.